# Iterating list of map for writing only its content

Tags: java, loops, dictionary, set

Each participant is voting some numerical values to each others, and I want to write this information by agent's name.

By the following code,

```
cj.makingDefault().stream()
       .forEach(a->out.print(a.entrySet()));
```

I get a List of Map printed which is,

```
[ari=[0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03], 
 hyo=[0.31, 0.31, 0.317, 0.31..., ji=[...], yoo=[...], mi=[...]..]
```

How can I print out only the numberic value by agents, separated by newline?

Desired results would be like

```
0.3, 0.3, 0.3, ...0.3
0.31, 0.31, 0.31, ...0.31,
...
```

If there would be 7 participants, 7 by 7 matrix.

Thank you in advance for your help~

edit)
As a temporary solution, I modified "cj.makingDefault()" function to return only Map<String, List> and changed code to this.

```
  cj.makingDefault().entrySet()
    .stream().forEach(a->out.print(a.getValue()+"\n"));
```

and I got

```
[0.0056009042654552865, 0.0056009042654552865, 0.0056009042654552865, 0.0056009042654552865, 0.0056009042654552865, 0.0056009042654552865, 0.0056009042654552865]
[0.31583809304895144, 0.31583809304895144, 0.31583809304895144, 0.31583809304895144, 0.31583809304895144, 0.31583809304895144, 0.31583809304895144]
[0.9924090841607273, 0.9924090841607273, 0.9924090841607273, 0.9924090841607273, 0.9924090841607273, 0.9924090841607273, 0.9924090841607273]
[0.8093898651356558, 0.8093898651356558, 0.8093898651356558, 0.8093898651356558, 0.8093898651356558, 0.8093898651356558, 0.8093898651356558]
[0.015200181208559038, 0.015200181208559038, 0.015200181208559038, 0.015200181208559038, 0.015200181208559038, 0.015200181208559038, 0.015200181208559038]
[0.03947825506938696, 0.03947825506938696, 0.03947825506938696, 0.03947825506938696, 0.03947825506938696, 0.03947825506938696, 0.03947825506938696]
[0.39173806385104337, 0.39173806385104337, 0.39173806385104337, 0.39173806385104337, 0.39173806385104337, 0.39173806385104337, 0.39173806385104337]
```

Then how can I eliminate the suqare braket of this..? it would be perfect..

Comment: What is type of `cj.makingDefault()` please ?

Comment: it returns List<Map<String, List<Double>>>......

Comment: Try `a.values()`. It returns a collection which you can print as desired

Comment: @user7, I used getValue to extract only number.. but still there is a problem..

Comment: Can you share more input and output as example ? To see for example where values of ji, yoo, mi will go. each Map does have just one entry ?

Comment: @azro yes.. as a temporary solution, I made it to have one entry but, later code had some changes.. it iterates through greater loop in order to print out 7by7 matrix.

Comment: Also `cj.makingDefault()` is not `List<Map<String, List<Double>>>` because you wouldn't be able to do .entrySet(), seems that it is directly a Map

Comment: @azro, yes.. you are right. As I getting the answer I changed the output of it to return Map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is the default `toString` implementation of a collection which will include the square brackets.

You have to print the elements in the list yourself.

```
cj.makingDefault().stream()
   .forEach(a -> print(a.values()));

 private void print(Collection<Double> values) {
    System.out.println(values.stream()
            .map(String::valueOf)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must first iterate the map values, that are lists, and then the items in those lists to override the standard toString output.

```
Map<String, List<Double>> map = ...

String result = map.values().stream()
        .map(s -> s.stream()
                .map(String::valueOf)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")))
        .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```